# Causing Issues in making random string using symbol defined

Tags: php

I want to generate a random string of 50 characters string using Letters, Numbers and Special Symbols.

Below Code is working Fine for me.

But the issue is that if I add Special Symbol **<**

I does not work as it should be

Kindly help.

```
<?php
$complete_string = NULL;
$generated_string = NULL;
$generated_string_length = 50;

$lower_case_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$upper_case_string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$numbers_string = '0123456789';
$special_symbols_string = ',./?;:"[]{}+=-_)(*&^%$#@!~`>'; // All Special Symbols without <

$complete_string = $complete_string.$lower_case_string.$upper_case_string.$numbers_string.$special_symbols_string;

$generated_string = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($complete_string, ceil($generated_string_length/strlen($complete_string)) )),1,$generated_string_length);

echo $generated_string;
?>
```

Comment: This code works both with and without '<'. Could you explain the problem?

Comment: Above Code is working fine as it generate 50 length random string, but if add special symbol < , it does not work then.

Comment: I tried to execute this on php 5.6 and php 7.1 with '<', every time I received a string, sometimes containing '<', with length of 50 symbols

Comment: i need every time bro :)
not sometimes :)

Comment: You can't recieve all symbols in your result every time, because your $complete_string is 91 symbols length, then you shuffle it and crop to 50 symbols. So you always loose 41 random symbol.

Comment: Also you have a lot of unnecessary code for $generated_string. You could replace: $generated_string = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($complete_string, ceil($generated_string_length/strlen($complete_string)) )),1,$generated_string_length);

by: $generated_string = substr(str_shuffle($complete_string), 0, $generated_string_length);

Comment: Bro, I think you are not getting the problem what i defined in question. my Code is working fine. But when i want to add < in special symbol, it does not work as it was working as.
That's the problem

Comment: What do you mean in "it does not work as it was working as"? It works the same with '<' and without '<'.

Comment: (Y) (Y) (Y) (Y) (Y)

Answer (score 1):

```
function randstr ($len=10, $abc="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,./?;:[]{}+=-_)(*&^%$#@!~`>") {
    $letters = str_split($abc);
    $str = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<=$len; $i++) {
        $str .= $letters[rand(0, count($letters)-1)];
    };
    return $str;
};

echo randstr(50);
```

Comment: $abc  = "dsadsad&*^%*^%^" as set your code as you want in random strings